# Why isn't kivy show text box

Tags: python, kivy

why isn't kivy show a text box for this code? please help me know how to let kivy add a text box by using this style.

thank you

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput



class textbox(GridLayout):
    def __initial__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyGrid, self).__initial__(**kwards)
        self.cols = 2
        self.add_widger(Label(text = "Point for good"))
        self.name = TextInput(multiline = False)
        self.add_widget(self.name)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    textbox().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any kivy program, You need to inherit from `App` class and override the `build` method and place your UI elements here, and call run() method from the instance of the class inheriting the the `App` class

secondly, its `add_widget()` not `add_widger` and perhaps you mean `__init__()` instead of `__initial__`

Here is the corrected code:

```py
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

class TextBox(App):
   

    def build(self):
        grid = GridLayout()
        grid.cols = 2
        grid.add_widget(Label(text = "Point for good"))
        name = TextInput(multiline = False)
        grid.add_widget(name)

        return grid

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TextBox().run()
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation! this is my first time using kivy! it taking a long time to run. is this normal?